# how to get lat and long in android

Tags: android, location

I am facing a minor problem in my code and getting stuck due to it.Following is my code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView1;
Location currentLocation;
double currentLatitude,currentLongitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    findLocation();

    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(currentLatitude) + "\n"
            + String.valueOf(currentLongitude));

}

 public void findLocation() {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                updateLocation(location,currentLatitude,currentLongitude);

                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        String.valueOf(currentLatitude) + "\n"
                                + String.valueOf(currentLongitude), 5000)
                        .show();

                }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

    }


    void updateLocation(Location location,double currentLatitude,double currentLongitude) {
            currentLocation = location;
            this.currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            this.currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();

        }
}
```

Every thing is working fine.But my problem is that the class level variables currentLatitude and currentLongitude having the values null.In the above code when i am setting the lat and long in text view in update location method,it works fine but when i want to set the same values in text view in on create method it gives null value.Why i dont know.Please help to sort out this problem.Thanks in advance!

Comment: set the textview values in `updateLocation` - in `onCreate` the location hasn't been found yet

Comment: It takes some time to update location.So set llat & long in textView inside updateLocation()

Comment: @BLaZuRE -because `findLocation();` is called before those are put in the `textView1.set...`.

Answer (score 1):

Its because When you set text in textview in Oncreate method lat and long is not initialized. it will get initialized when it gets updated.

so you should settext in updatelocation() method.

locationlistener take sometime to update its lat and long so that your oncreate method is executed meanwhile so that your lat and long is not updated and stays null. so its better to settext on updatelocation.

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Thanks bro! but i want these class level variables to be used in another class .How can i do that?

Comment: use variable in another class means you want values to use in another class??

Comment: yeah..Actually i want to create the object of this class by making it a simple java class and want to use these variables in another class.

Comment: You can't get value by creating object. if you create object so that variable will get another instance so that you can't have values. you need to store this values somewhere like Shared Preference and get it in another class.

Comment: srry bro. but i don't know that. if you can implement that then do inform me. it will be helpful to me as well.

Comment: class Temp{
  
  int x;
  int y;
  
  Temp(int x,int y){
   
   this.x=x;
   this.y=y;
   
  }
  
  void show(){
   
   System.out.println(x);
   System.out.println(y);
  }
  
  public static void main(String...s){
   
  Temp t1=new Temp(10,20);
  t1.show();
  
  Temp t1=new Temp(100,200);
  t1.show();
  }
  
  
 }

Comment: you are passing X n Y values from constructor. so that it will get values in show method that's right. but if i create another object and try to access values that previous object has set then you won't get that.

Comment: I think we can use the copy constructor for that purpose to copy the first object values to the other

Comment: Dynamic initialization of instance data member means when the object created then the data members will get the values inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put `textView1.setText(String.valueOf(currentLatitude) + "\n"
            + String.valueOf(currentLongitude));` in the `updateLocation` function.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the location takes some time before it returns with values. It happens asynchronously and meanwhile your UI thread continues.

So in `onCreate()`, you have no location yet. It doesn't matter the order of the calls in `onCreate()`.

You *only* get location when your `updateLocation()` method is called, and there is no guarantee of when that happens in relation to your views being set up.

So, to fix, update your textView texts in there.

```
void updateLocation(Location location,double currentLatitude,double currentLongitude) {
    currentLocation = location;
    this.currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
    this.currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(currentLatitude) + "\n"
        + String.valueOf(currentLongitude));
}
```